# Credentials work for SSMS but not (ODBC) LogParser script

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql, odbc

Via SSMS I'm able to connect and navigate the server/db in question. but trying to connect via a logparser script the same credentials fail. I'm trying to execute this from the same box on which the server's running. the username is owner/dbo of the db. The db has mixed mode authentication.

[linebreaks for clarity]

> C:\TTS\tools\LogParser>c:\tts\tools\logparser\logparser
>   file:c:\tts\tools\logparser\errors2SQL.sql?source="C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC8\u_ex100521.log"
>
> -i:IISW3C
>
> -o:SQL
>
> -createTable:ON
>
> -oConnString:"Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0};Server=servername\SQLEXPRESS;db=Tter;uid=logger2;pwd=foo"
>
> -stats:OFF   Task aborted. Error connecting to ODBC Server   SQL State:
>   28000   Native Error:  18456   Error
>   Message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native
>   Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login   failed
>   for user 'logger2'.
>   C:\TTS\tools\LogParser>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by explicitly terminating the password field with a semicolon. I had been using a script from a prior install and apparently previous versions of ODBC were more tolerant.

...uid=logger2;pwd=foo;"